# Table sort declining constantly standing

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Im using this bootstrap jquery plugin and its working, but always i need to click to sort some columns. I want to my percent in column stay sorted constantly.

```
http://www.jqueryscript.net/table/jQuery-Plugin-For-Sortable-Bootstrap-Tables-Bootstrap-Sortable.html
```

If someone can edit and show me how to implement. Thanks

Comment: This is not a tutorial site. Google will be your best friend during these difficult times. When you begin to write some code and have a specific question regarding code, that's where we're here to help.

Comment: I understand. Script offers data-firstsort="desc", but when i put it i need to click to column to sort.
    // sort direction
    var sortKey = $this.attr('data-sortkey');
    var initialDirection = $this.attr('data-firstsort') !== 'desc' ? 'desc' : 'asc';


this is from jquery, but i  dont know how to auto sort by default